# How to use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler to show exception message on UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, exception, uiview

I use Martin R's answer to print the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in Swift.

[How should I use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441302/how-should-i-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-in-swift/31770435#31770435)

```
  func exceptionHandler(exception : NSException) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Exception", message: "\(exception)", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    print(exception)
    print(exception.callStackSymbols)
}
```

But how can I display the message in a UIView. Like this one

[image]

Because I got a compiler error message said that "A C function pointer can only be formed from a reference to a 'func' or a literal closure."

[Handling unhandled exceptions and signals](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html) written by Matt Gallagher at Cocoa with Love.

[image]

Comment: have you tried exception.name or exception.reason?

Comment: @Horst, I would like to show the message on screen, user can capture and send it back.

Comment: You're not showing your entire code

Comment: @newacct I am new to Swift, about 1 year only. I am trying to convert the code written by Matt From ObjC to Swift. It can be compiled, but can not be run. an error message 'Thread 1: singal SIGABRT' in main.m at the line 'int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);'

Comment: @charles.cc.hsu: I'm confused. Didn't you say you got a compile error?

Comment: @newacct Yes. compiler error. Now I can bridge the C function to Swift, but how can I do it only in swift?

Comment: I am trying this same. Same error I am receiving. How did u solve this ?? @charles.cc.hsu  Now I am striking in the same error. I need to mail that error. But I cant.

Answer (score 0):

`NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` takes a C function pointer, and C function bodies are fixed at compile-time. C function pointers get bridged into Swift 2 as `@convention(c)` function types, and, like in C, you can only pass a function whose body can be fixed at compile-time; i.e. top-level Swift functions, or anonymous function which don't capture any variables.

Your anonymous function captures `self` from the enclosing scope, so it cannot be used as a C function. You should try to access the controller or do whatever you need to do in some other way using only global variables or classes.

Comment: Thanks you! I will follow your suggestion to figure out the solution. Before that, I maybe just keep the original C function and use bridge to work with Swift.

Comment: @charles.cc.hsu: How would you write it as a C function? If you can answer that they you can write it in Swift without capturing any variables.

Comment: I am still struggling against converting the [C code](https://github.com/Charles-Hsu/UncaughtExceptions/blob/master/Classes/UncaughtExceptionHandler.m) to Swift, because I am not familiar with ObjC also. The UncaughtExceptionHandler.m is too low level function for me. I don't know what is the meaning of 'volatile' and how to convert it to Swift (somewhere in SO said use memset_s). Second, the code use UIAlertView is deprecated, I also do not know how to convert it to UIAlertController, because UncaughtExceptionHandler is subclass of NSObject only.

Comment: Here is a solution [UIAlertController from any NSObject subclass] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472321/how-do-i-display-uialertcontroller-from-any-nsobject-subclass), I will give it a try.

Comment: how will the memory be freed?

Comment: @newacct    I am trying this same. Same error I am receiving. How did u solve this ?? Now I am striking in the same error. I need to mail that error. But I cant.

Comment: @McDonal_11: Well, how would you do it in C? Basically, the function used cannot capture any variables from an outside scope. It can only use global variables.

Comment: @newacct   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265162/xcode7-how-to-mail-crash-report-in-swift    This my question. Pls guide me.

Answer (score -1):

with the use of NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

```
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            print("EXception Details Are \n\nExceptionName--> \(exception.name) \nReason -->\(exception.reason!)\n\(exception.description)")
            print(exception.callStackSymbols)
        }
```

Comment: try explaining a bit more

Comment: I am trying this same. Same error I am receiving. How did u solve this ?? Now I am striking in the same error. I need to mail that error. But I cant