# Xcode7: How to mail crash report in swift

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My small task is, how to mail crash report? I don't know whether this example is right or wrong.

**Coding:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func exceptionHandler(exception : NSException) {
            print("\n\n \(exception)")
            print("\n\n \(exception.callStackSymbols)")


            mailAcn() // SENDING MAIL ACTION WHEN EXCEPTION CAUGHT
        }

        NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler) //Error: A C Function pointer cannot be formed from a local function captures context


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

I am following this link,, 
[How to use NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler to show exception message on UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952611/how-to-use-nssetuncaughtexceptionhandler-to-show-exception-message-on-uiview-in)

Some unknown error is receiving. Kindly guide me, how to solve this?

Comment: Install Fabric by Twitter. It's free and very easy to setup.

Comment: Is there any other way? @avismara  to test with simulator ??

Comment: Not that I know of. On a side note, why would you need a mailing mechanism if you are on a simulator anyway? You'll directly get to see the problem in the console, right?

Comment: Right.. but this is my task !!! thats it... !! and I am new to this crash report mail concept...

Comment: Looks like you have a weird task in hand. Usually, the crash logs on the simulator are stored at ` ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`. See if you can take it from there.

Comment: Visit <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team>

Answer (score 0):

`mailAcn()` means `self.mailAcn()`, i.e. it is calling an instance method on `self`. Thus, the function captures the variable `self` from the surrounding scope, and it cannot be used as a C function.

You can try to make `mailAcn` a top-level function instead.